# Simplify the expectation of the maximum of two random variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

*My aim is to simplify the maximum of two expressions each of which are a function of exponentially distributed random variables*

**Given**: positive constants $a,b,c,d$. Independent random variables $x,y \sim exp(\lambda) \mbox{ i.e., } f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \text{ and }  g(y)=\lambda e^{-\lambda y} $ where $\lambda$ is the rate. Take $\lambda=1$ for simplicity.

**Question**
Simplify the expression

\begin{equation*}
H(x,y) = \mathbb{E} \left( \max (a+bx, c+dy) \right)
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbb{E}$ is the expectation operator. This is simplified as follows using the property that $x$ and $y$ are independent.

\begin{equation*}
H(x,y) = \int \left[ \int _{x_0}^{\infty}  (a+bx)f(x)dx + \int _{-\infty}^{x_0}  (c+dy)f(x)dx \right] f(y)dy
\end{equation*} 
where $x_0 \equiv \frac{c+dy-a}{b}$. Hence it becomes

\begin{equation*}
H(x,y) = \int \left[ \int _{x_0}^{\infty}  (a+bx)e^{-x}dx + \int _{-\infty}^{x_0}  (c+dy)e^{-x}dx \right] e^{-y}dy
\end{equation*} 
I need help simplify this expression further.